# Unable to deploy AWS Instances through CF Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

Unable to deploy AWS Instances through CF Stack. Getting error code DocumentLimitExceeded.

Error:

Resource handler returned message:

"Limit exceeded for resource of type 'AWS::SSM::Document'.
Reason: Service returned error code DocumentLimitExceeded

Service: Ssm,
Status Code: 400,
Request ID: ffc2d953-b812-445e-b08a-4ea79fd6657"

RequestToken: 4c5eda9d-f262-e567-6e03-ce5e703f30c,
HandlerErrorCode: ServiceLimitExceeded

Not understanding how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: According to docs this indicate more than 500 SSM parameters. Is this your case?

Comment: I am not aware. You mean I have to extend ssm parameter limit ?

Comment: You would need to have 500 existing parameter entries in your Parameter Store. If you don't think you do then go check that in the AWS Console system manager section - it's possible you may have run some tests/loops that created so many entries.